# Having Trouble Seeing Why Friedman's Theorem (1973) is true.

Tags: logic, foundations, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

I am reading about non-standard models of peano arithmetic, and came across a theorem by *Friedman* that states the following.

> Every non-standard countable model of (peano) arithmetic is isomorphic to an initial segment of itself.

There seems to be little available to non-academics on this subject, and although I can accept that the theorem is true, I cannot think of why it is true, nor of a concrete example of an isomorphism between a countable non-standard model and an initial segment of itself.

**Question:** What would such an isomorphism look like, and is there a nice and/or intuitive way of thinking of this?

Comment: Due to _Tennenbaum's theorem_ it is practically impossible to _think of_ a countable non-standard model of PA in the first place, or imagine what it looks like, much less what its internal isomorphisms look like.

Comment: I have mostly been considering the example presented in [this](https://boolesrings.org/victoriagitman/2015/04/22/an-introduction-to-nonstandard-models-of-arithmetic/) article, where the first segment is $\mathbb{N}$ followed by countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ indexed by $\mathbb{Q}$. Is this an incorrect way of thinking of countable non-standard models of peano arithmetic?

Comment: @mathfan27543: That is what they look like just as ordered sets, but that doesn't tell you much about what their addition and multiplication look like.

Comment: @EricWofsey Is it necessary to know what the addition and multiplication tables are in order to provide an example of this theorem?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you would consider to be an "example", but the addition and multiplication tables are part of what it means to have a model of PA...

Comment: In any case, I think it is extremely unrealistic to expect to be able to understand "why" a theorem is true without actually diving into the proof.  You could perhaps understand why the theorem is plausible (i.e., why it is not obviously false), but that is much weaker.

Comment: Barring a concrete example, is there much else that we can say/know about this topic other than that the proof is true?